# Рассылка автоматических уведомлений с сайта в Телеграм

Tags: telegram

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли настроить систему отправки автоматических уведомлений с сайта в телеграм зарегестрированным пользователям?

На сайте есть пул авторов, на которых подписываются пользователи, необходимо, чтобы при выходе нового текста пользователю приходило уведомление в телегу.

Comment: «возможно ли настроить систему отправки автоматических уведомлений с сайта» — да.

Comment: Да, настраивайте.